# Directly access sub menu

Tags: menu, mega-menu

I have a menu with main items and sub items like this:

- **Ferrari**
- Testarossa
- F40
- **Volvo**
- V40
- V60
- **Saab**
- 9-3
- 9-5

I now have this selection in one drop down menu with sub menus, which works but I have three main problems with that solution:

- The user can't, for example, see that it is a Ferrari when the F40 is selected (since the drop down only show selected menu entry value). Naming all the sub entries "Ferarri Testarossa", "Ferarri F40" etc isn't an opition.
- The user can't select just Ferrari and get a default model selected.
- The user can't directly change model within Ferrari if Ferarri is the selected main brand.

I don't think it's a good idea to have 2 (regular) drop down menus, one with the brand and one with the model since the user have to change two menus to go from one brand to another...

**The one thing I really would like is a controller where you can either load a default model for a brand (for example, pressing Ferrari shows the first sub item F40), or manually getting to choose the models.**

Since it's a generic controller for different situation, the solution doesn't have to be aimed for car brands. A good solution will work for anything with item with sub lists.

Do you have any good suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: "*Naming all the sub entries "Ferarri Testarossa", "Ferarri F40" etc isn't an opition."* - why is this not an option? It might not be perfect visually, but at least it would be accurate.

Comment: Well, it's not an option because the rest of the problems won't be solved.

Comment: I think some context can help us better understand your problem. Approximately how many brands are you planning to have, and how many models per brand? Since you mention 2 clicks to go to a different brand is too much, how often will users actually do this? Is it something that you do once, or a recurring thing (like a racing video game or a comparison tool)?

Comment: Well, in many cases the users will select the brand, and then explore the models. And some times, the user will change brand and explore that brands models. I would like some examples on different ways of going through main entries and sub entries - beside the one drop down menu way...

Comment: If there isn't a page dedicated to the Ferrari, Volvo, etc, then those aren't a level of navigation--they are merely headers to group navigation underneath. As such, there's no need for 'two levels' of navigation. You just need to come up with a nice visual design to make it clear that those are merely grouping headers of navigable links.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is the best option, but perhaps one to consider. [Miller Columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_Columns)

You could have one drop down that would 'slide' to get to the secondary level to make the actual selection.

Initial state:

```
Select a Vehicle \/
```

Once selected

```
Select a Vehicle \/
-------------------
Ferrari           >
Volvo             >
Saab              >
```

And then once they select a make, the makes slide to the left and the models come into view (in this example they selected Ferrari)

```
Select a Vehicle \/
-------------------
< Make
• Testarossa        
• F40
```

I like miller columns because they are compact, and if the interaction is done well, rather intuitive, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Most auto sites already have the make and model separated into 2 drop down menus.

Example: http://wwwa.autotrader.ca

[image: autotrader]

If it must be in a dropdown, why not have the Make's logo beside the Model name?

Similar to:

[image: icon list example]

Answer (score 0):

A tiered menu could be a solution for this. If the child menu items appear the moment you roll-over a parent and the clickable menu buttons are visually distinguishable from the non clickable item, I don't think it is a problem that the parent isn't clickable.